# Can't access Event Viewer logs after a BSOD

Tags: bsod, event-viewer

I hope this is an okay place to ask this.  My issue is fairly similar to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158820/right-clicking-on-any-event-inside-the-windows-7-event-viewers-application-log) that was closed and directed to SuperUser.  However, I'm on Windows 10 and the hotfix, even if applicable, is no longer available.

I got a BSOD 3 weeks ago that mentioned memory management and wanted to check out the log to get more info.  When I try to view instances of the Critical event type, I get the following error message.

[image]

Previously, when I chose the unload option, it would result in a stack trace and nothing worked anymore.  However, now it just causes the event viewer to lock up.  If you want the stack trace, let me know and I can try to get to it.  The shut down option obviously doesn't let me view the logs either.

Nothing else is having issues and I haven't gotten any BSODs since that day.  The RAM is 2.5 years old and was tested on purchase to be fine.

I'm on OS build 17134.829, version 1803.

Comment: You should use **windbg** to analyze the dump file that was created.  You don’t indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using.  Indicate what the last cumulative patch that was installed.

Comment: Didn't even think to use windbg outside of work, but that will only answer my original question and not fix the event viewer.

Comment: The solution to that question likely will solve both problems.  If you boot into Safe Mode does the behavior still happen?

Comment: Haven't tried yet.  I'll try out both tomorrow.

Comment: I have no dump file even though I should be set up to get them.  I get this [interesting message](https://i.imgur.com/CWDLznf.png) when I try to mess with the dump file settings even though you can see the page file.  Oh well, I'll still try out safe mode.

Comment: The fact you get a message indicating there is a problem with the page file, indicates to me your problem with the Event Viewer, is due to that same problem.  I first reboot your machine, if that didn't work, I would disable the page file and enable it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96009/discussion-between-ramhound-and-lukini).